# What's the minimum an application needs to be considered an Ajax application?

Tags: ajax

Is anything that uses JavaScript and asynchronous communication of XML data considered Ajax?

Comment: hahah assynchronous i hope that's intentional

Comment: anything with jquery.... (haha just kidding)

Answer (score 1):

Most people who deal with [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) would consider any usage of [`XMLHttpRequest`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) to be AJAX.

This doesn't mean that the request need be async either.

These days, JSON replaces XML for communications.

From wikipedia:

> With Ajax, web applications can send data to, and retrieve data from, a server asynchronously (in the background) without interfering with the display and behavior of the existing page. Data is usually retrieved using the XMLHttpRequest object. Despite the name, the use of XML is not needed (JSON is often used instead), and the requests need not be asynchronous.

Answer (score 0):

AJAX seems to encompass any application which retrieves data using the XMLHttpRequest object. Despite it's name you don't need to use XML and I'd wager most AJAX apps these days are using JSON instead. Also they don't necessarily make *asynchronous* requests. We probably need a new buzzword at this point. Maybe *websockets* will take off!

Answer (score 0):

The term AJAX and its abbreviation is a misnomer. It has nothing to do with XML. It typically refers to the [`XMLHttpRequest`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) function. The name of this function again is a misnomer because you could use it to get or send JSON data, plain text, or even binary data now.

`AsyncHttpRequest` would have been a more appropriate term for the function, and `AJAH` (Asynchronous JavaScript and HTML) instead of AJAX. On a side note, although XMLHttpRequest allows synchronous requests too, they'd probably be better off getting rid of it altogether.

Typically AJAX applications make good use of asynchronous calls and avoid page refreshes as much as possible. [Gmail](http://www.gmail.com) is a good example. [Facebook](http://www.facebook.com), on a modern browser, also uses AJAX. Clicking on different links like "News Feed", "Events", etc. doesn't cause a page reload although the path in the address bar changes. [Github](http://www.github.com) does the same on modern browsers.